# Where is adopted storage mounted?

Tags: mount, adoptable-storage

Where in the filesystem is the mountpoint for the adoptable storage partition?

Answer (score 0):

On my Dirty Unicorns ROM, I found it mounted under `/mnt/expand`.

If it's not there try looking through the output of:

- `mount | grep dm-`
- `mount | grep block`

Comment: Same on a LineageOS 18 (Android 11)